# How to enter values into a web page and click on a checkbox using python

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I'm trying to enter values into a webpage and click on accept using the following code.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

url = "https://www.mahadiscom.in/"



value={'consumer_no':170687006****,
      'terms': 'Yes',
       'vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3- 
style-modern vc_btn3-color-juicy-pink.submit':True
    }

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(value)
data = data.encode('ascii')

req = urllib.request.Request(url,data)

with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
   the_page = response.read()

string = re.search('^You have selected to pay', str(the_page))
```

I have attached an image of the form where i'm trying to fill the data.

[Form I'm trying to fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkB6Y.png)

I'm wondering if this is even the way to do it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with requests.

You can do it easily using [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/).

## Example

### Click

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('path to chromedriver')
driver.get('website url')

button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('css selector')
button.click()
```

### Write text to form input

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('path to chromedriver')
driver.get('website url')

text_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('css selector')
text_input.send_keys('hello world')
```